Existence of vector bundle isomorphism iff there exists a frame of section: Why smooth?
While doing this exercise: Existence of vector bundle isomorphism iff there exists a frame of sections I had some trouble to formally prove that the map they define (which I also came up with):
$$ F\colon M\times \mathbb R^n \to E\colon \, (p,x = (x_i))\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n x_i s_i(p)
$$  is actually a smooth map between manifolds. I am new to smooth manifolds so excuse me if this question is trivial.
Is there an effective argument to show that a map like this is smooth? I get that you have smooth map $ \{p\} \times \mathbb R^n \to E_p$ for each $p \in M$ and that given $x \in \mathbb R^n$, the maps $p \mapsto x_i \cdot s_i(p)$ will all be smooth. But I do not see how (or even if?) this implies smoothness in both coordinates. Thank you in advance!

This is a vector calculus exercise (product of smooth functions).
